# Tabularizing text file data

Tags: csv, awk, sed

I've a text file with information in this format.

```
%%%
key1 = value1
key2 = value2
key3 = subkey1:subvalue1;subkey2:subvalue2
%%%
key1 = value1
key2 = value2
key3 = subkey1:subvalue1;subkey2:subvalue2
%%%
```

I want to convert this to this CSV like format:

```
key1,key2,key3_subkey1,key3_subkey2
value1,value2,subvalue1,subvalue2
value1,value2,subvalue1,subvalue2
```

What is the best way to do this. I'm hoping there are unix utilities like Awk/Sed/Grep that can be used instead of write a python/perl program that reads each line, maintains state and converts to csv format

Comment: Could you please do add your efforts which you have put in order to solve your own problem in your question and let us know then.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS = "[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*"
    OFS = ","
}
!/%%%/ {
    hdrs = hdrs sep $1
    n = split($2,subFlds,/[:;]/)
    if ( n == 1 ) {
        vals = vals sep $2
        sep = OFS
    }
    else {
        for ( i=1; i<=n; i+=2) {
            hdrs = hdrs sep subFlds[i]
            vals = vals sep subFlds[i+1]
        }
        if ( !doneHdr++) {
            print hdrs
        }
        print vals
        hdrs = vals = sep = ""
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
key1,key2,key3,subkey1,subkey2
value1,value2,subvalue1,subvalue2
value1,value2,subvalue1,subvalue2
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how much easier you could get than doing a quick manual parse on this. The code below will even handle any set of keys and arbitrary keys with subkeys thanks to Pandas' building the table.

```
data = []

for line in open('input.txt'):
    if line.startswith('%%%'):
        o = {}
        data.append(o)
        continue

    key, value = line.strip().split(' = ')
    if ':' in value:
        for pairstring in value.split(';'):
            subkey, subvalue = pairstring.split(':')
            o[f'{key}_{subkey}'] = subvalue
    else:
        o[key] = value

import pandas

pandas.DataFrame.from_records(data).to_csv('output.csv')
```